# storybook v7 beta, viewports and other options disappear on startup

Tags: next.js, storybook, nextjs-storybook

I'm trying to setup my storybook environment and while it mostly works fine, the viewport tab, and other options, disappear on build/start. I'm not sure what's going on here, I haven't seen any information regarding it and I've been removing features from my SB environment to fix it ... so far to no avail. Any guidance would be appreciated.

`storybook/preview.js` -- emptied it of all content

`storybook/main.js` (below)

```
module.exports = {
  stories: ['../src/**/*.mdx', '../src/**/*.stories.@(js|jsx|ts|tsx)'],
  addons: [
    '@storybook/addon-links',
    '@storybook/addon-essentials',
    '@storybook/addon-interactions'
  ],
  framework: {
    name: '@storybook/nextjs',
    options: {}
  },
  docs: {
    docsPage: true
  }
};
```

step for video below:

1. run `npm run storybook`
2. open new browser tab

while building:

[image]

after building:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I've just found out that actually after version 7, the viewport button only appear on canvas and not in the docs anymore.